# Sharepoint Foundation 2013, Azure

Tags: azure, sharepoint-2013

I have been trying to install Sharepoint Foundation 2013 in Azure.Its been two days and i have been unable to do so.I could find no tutorials for it that do so via azure.Can someone show me any tutorials?I am trying to install sharepoint foundation in a vm(Microsoft Server 2012).I am just a beginner.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you [tried this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d81734ab-6371-4887-9659-f1fb0a2c0d30/sharepoint-foundation-server-2013-on-azure?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows)?

Comment: I have to install sharepoint foundation 2013, i understand they are similiar .

Comment: and it gives no details , on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial for better understanding and step-by-step configuration

https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2014/10/create-sharepoint-2013-farm-in-azure-step-step.html